# Gradebook sum issue in Python

Tags: python

I am doing a grade book for school and am having an issue trying to get the grade_total to work. After many different tries and places, I just cant get the total to work. It prints the grades you entered and thats all.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
subject_grade = {}

stop = False

while not stop:
    print("")
    print("Welcome To Your Grade Book!    ")
    name = input("Student Name:\n")
    
    subject = input("Subject Name:\n")
    
    test = input("Enter Test Score:\n")
    
    quiz = input("Enter Quiz Grade\n")
    
    assignment = input("Enter Assignment Grade\n")
    
    subject_grade = {'test_score':test, 'quiz_score':quiz, 'assignment_grade':assignment}
    subject_history = []
    response = input("Would You Like To Enter Another Item?\n Type 'C' to Continue or 'Q' 
    to quit:\n")
    if response == 'q':
        stop = True
        print("Thanks For Your Input!")
    if response == 'c':
        stop = False
        subject_grade.append()     


#Function calculates average 
def grade_total(test, quiz, assignment):
    result = test + quiz + assignment
    return result
    sum = (test, assignment, quiz)
    result = sum(test+quiz+assignment)    

    print('The Sum Is', result)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `return result` ends the function. Nothing after that is executed.

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: You're missing the argument to append in `subject_grade.append()`

Comment: `append()` is a list method, but `subject_grade` is a dictionary. What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: You never append anything to the `subject_history` list. What is that for?

Comment: You say it prints the grades you entered, but I don't see any code that does that.

Comment: If `subject_history` is supposed to hold all the `subject_grade` dictionaries, you should initialize it before the loop, and append to it each time through the loop.

Comment: Then when you want to calculate the total grade, you should loop through that list.

Comment: There's so much missing from the code you posted, I don't see any way to fix it. I would have to write all the missing code for you, but that would be cheating.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on the `grade_total()` function since that what you're referring to.

#### Your code

First, let's have a look at the code you posted. I added line numbers for reference.

```
1  def grade_total(test, quiz, assignment):
2      result = test + quiz + assignment    
3      return result                        
4      sum = (test, assignment, quiz)       
5      result = sum(test+quiz+assignment)   
6  
7      print('The Sum Is', result)
```

- **Line 2**: This does the thing what you want (probably): Take the sum of individual scores and store the result in the `result` variable
- **Line 3**: Here, you return the `result` to the caller of the function, which is fine. **But**: The `return` statement tells the interpreter (i.e. the program running your script) to exit the function. So, lines 4 through 7 won't be executed
- **Line 4**: Here, you create a tuple (immutable list) of the individual scores. Also, you assign it to `sum`, which is a built-in function.
- **Line 5**: This would be an alternative to line 2: Call the [built-in function `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with the individual scores as arguments. But the call should look like this: `result = sum(test, quiz, assignment)`
- **Line 7**: The print call is fine, it just isn't executed (because of line 3)

#### Improved version

I think this should do the trick:

```
def grade_total(test, quiz, assignment):
    result = sum(test, quiz, assignment)
    print('The Sum Is', result)

    return result
```

Comment: I tried that but it does nothing. I feel like I'm getting closer though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it has to do with the placement of the if response == 'q: because after i run it enter info and click q to quit it stops and nothing follows